# Looping an Offset "up" a column

Tags: vba

I'm looking to loop up a column, offsetting by one row and adding 1 to the value of the row below:

Example:

A
1.....8
2.....7
3.....6
4.....5

I've built the code (shared below) to identify and fill the correct value of the bottom row (based off another spreadsheet) and filled the cell above. But struggling to get it to loop up to the top row in the column (A7)

```
Dim wscombined As Worksheet
Dim wspsimp As Worksheet

Set wscombined = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2013-2018 Combined")
Set wspsimp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pipeline simplified")
u = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(wscombined.Range("A7:A50"))

'Fill latest new completed transaction with next UniqueID

LastRowU = wspsimp.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(LastRowU, 8).Offset(, -7).Value = u + 1

Z = Cells(LastRowU, 8).Offset(, -7)
Cells(LastRowU, 8).Offset(-1, -7).Value = Z + 1
```

Comment: You should always fully specify ranges.

Comment: What is u? What is LastRowU? What is Z? BTW, if you want to "loop", [you will need to have a loop somewhere](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/looping-through-code)... there is non here.

Comment: A loop upwards could be achievable with `For i = LastRowU To 1 Step -1` with `i` being the row number